# Is there a good Windows equivalent to Podworks?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, ipod

[Podworks](http://www.scifihifi.com/podworks/) is a pretty great Mac app that lets you get music off an iPod.

Is there a good Windows equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to Copy Music & Movies Off Your iPod or iPhone](http://www.methodshop.com/gadgets/ipodsupport/copyoff/index.shtml):

Here are a few commercial or trial version applications:

- [PD+Rescue for iPod Win/Mac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BNGI7K)
- [Tune Transfer for iPod](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007U9BSU)
- [Xilisoft iPhone Transfer (PC)](http://www.xilisoft.com/iphone-transfer.html)
- [Xilisoft iPod Rip (PC)](http://www.xilisoft.com/ipod-rip.html)

Here's a way to quickly get files off a PC iPod without any extra software:

1. Plug your iPod or iPhone into your computer.
2. From the Desktop, go to My Computer and find the iPod (usually designated by a drive letter. i e. E: or F:)
3. Open the damn thing.
4. Go to Tools > Folder Options > View (the tab) > scroll to Show Hidden Files and Folders and click it.
5. Click OK.
6. Go back to your iPod folder/drive, there you will find a new folder called iPod_Control
7. Open it.
8. The Music folder in it will have a bunch of folders named F00, F01 and so on. THEY HAVE YOUR MP3s AND VIDEOS. Look through the folders to find your stuff.
9. You can also use the Search utility in Windows and search for a particular audio file on your iPod. Just make sure you specify to search in Hidden Files or Folders.

Comment: @harrymc You could also add SharePod [ http://www.getsharepod.com/ ] to the list